# Retrieving data from stored procedure's cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, java, cursors

I want to use the ResultSet in java program to get data from Stored procedure's cursor. Is that possible with SQL Server?

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SampleProcedure AS 
DECLARE @FirstName varchar(64)
DECLARE @LastName varchar(64)
DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT FROM c1
INTO @FirstName, @LastName


CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

When I use `EXEC SampleProcedure`, I just got the output as "Command(s) completed successfully" and the Resultset shows null in java program. So what to change in my code so that my ResultSet retrieves data?

I want to know how to prepare ResultSet in the SQL Server code so that I can retrieve the same in java program.

Comment: you can play here: http://rextester.com/TKYO61267  and a tutorial here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2356/overview-of-with-result-sets-feature-of-sql-server-2012/

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server stored procedures can return record-sets from a query, a `CURSOR` would not be required (unlike in Oracle). The query below is all that's needed to get a recordset:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SampleProcedure 
AS 
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE
```